# Am I using my metatags the right way?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, visitors

I don't seem to get any visitors to my blog. Am I using my **metatags** the right way?

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="description" content="TechCloud is a place for tech-lovers, or newbies: You can enjoy quality reviews, tutorials, hacks and more... You can also request a tutorial or ask me any a question."> <meta name="keywords" content="technology, news, techcloud, home, reviews, tutorials, giveaways, sugru, sony, action, cam, cedric, dhaenens, phonebloks, jane, suki, ferguson, hacks, tips, tricks, engadget, lifehacker"> <meta name="author" content="Cedric Dhaenens"> <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"> <meta name="revisit-after" content="3 days">
```

techcloud.comlu.com

Comment: As far as I know the keywords meta tag is no longer noticed by Google. SEO will involve more than meta tags: clear code, good, frequently-updated content, and links from genuine websites will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with unor.  I use to work for an advertising company. Google crawlers do not look at metatags the way webcrawlers use too.  Try using [webgrader](http://marketing.grader.com) to see what you might need to add to your blog to get more attention.

I included a link to another discussion:

[Stackoverflow SEO discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14056)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are using the `meta` elements correctly.

Assuming that you are using HTML5: all the `name` values that you’ve used are [defined in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#standard-metadata-names) resp. [registered in the wiki](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions), so that’s fine.

Your assumption seems to be that you would get more visitors thanks to your `meta` elements. If or to which extent this might be true depends on many different factors, and none of these are ontopic here on Stack Overflow. Have a look around at [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) for that topic.